# Como executar uma função opcionalmente se a página for carregada dentro de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Tem como saber se determinada página está sendo aberta dentro de um `iframe`?

Quero que essa página execute uma função quando a mesma for carregada através de um `iframe`. Caso contrário, quero que não execute.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que é possível com `window.frameElement`. Estou no celular e não consigo testar, mas acho que é a solução. Se não me engano, o valor fica `null` quando a página não é carregada dentro do iframe.

Answer (score 0):

A sugestão do @AndersonCarlosWoss pode dar erro de segurança.
Tem um comentário (em inglês) aqui: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-frameelement

Uma solução que encontrei, foi neste post do SO em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769187/4730201

O código é esse:

```
var ehFrame = window.frames.length + ':' + parent.frames.length;
```

Basicamente retorna:

`'0:0'` quando não há frames
`'1:1'` quando executado na janela "pai" que tem o iframe
`'0:1'` quando executado na janela "filha"

Acho que isso deve te ajudar.